# Nodal displacement in ABAQUS using python script

Tags: python, abaqus

I want to get the U2 displacement of a particular node using a python script :

```
dy = odb.steps['LoadingStep'].frames[-1].fieldOutputs['U'].values[node_no].data[1]
```

The problem is that the `[value index]` doesn't match the node number. Meaning that the output for the 10th node can't be found using `values[10]`.

How can I get the displacement of a particular node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that there is some error in your index value (for example node with a label '10' is accessible by the index '9').

First, try to check in the Abaqus Viewer python interpreter if your are getting the right node with your `node_no`:

```py
nd = odb.rootAssembly.instaces['MY_INSTANCE'].nodes[node_no]
highlight(nd)
```

> Note that it will be much easier if, during the generation of your model, you define a `Set` with your node(s) of interest: after you can access them as easy as:
>
> ```py
> for nd in odb.rootAssembly.nodeSets['MY_NODE_SET']:
>    print(nd.label)
> ```

When you identified your node you can get a subset of your FieldOutput, so you will not be bothered by the order of elements in the FieldValueArray `values`:

```py
fieldU = frame.fieldOutputs['U']
ndFieldU = fieldU.getSubset(region=my_node, position=NODAL)
ndU2 = ndFieldU.values[0].data[1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have the node numbers for which I need the displacement. but when I write the following line, 
dy = odb.steps['Pullout'].frames[-1].fieldOutputs['U'].getSubset(region=node_index, position=NODAL).values[0].dataDouble[1]

ABAQUS says : TypeError: region; found int, expecting OdbInstance.


I have passed the node number as node_index, what shall I send as the argument region?

Comment: Well, the error message is quite self-explanatory: the method `getSubset` takes an object which should *specify the region for which to extract values* (http://abaqus.software.polimi.it/v6.14/books/ker/default.htm?startat=pt01ch34pyo06.html#ker-fieldoutput-getsubset2-pyc). If you look at the documentation you will see that different object types are accepted as the "region" by this method, but the `int` is not one of them. In the present example the type of `my_node` should be `OdbMeshNode` or an `OdbSet` containing your node of interest.

Comment: Could you mark the answer as 'accepted' if it resolves the problem?